# Is it possible to use PDT to debug through a tunnel with XDebug?

Tags: php, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I'm trying to debug using PDT and Xdebug over a tunnel and haven't been able to get PDT to connect properly.  I do not have PHP installed on the machine I am developing on and would like to connect to the XDebug instance that is running on my development machine that is not able to talk directly with my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The xdebug instance on your dev machine has to connect to the eclipse instance on your machine if you want to debug, so I guess the answer to your question is "no".